Proper way to replace bottom siding?
I see this question has been asked many times but I have an unusual wrinkle (I think).
I recently had a deck replaced with pavers. The deck had entombed some siding in a weird place where the level of the foundation changes and of course it rotted.
https://imgur.com/a/l0Z4qFE
I had the sense (at least it seemed wise at the time) to remove the rotted siding to prevent it being entombed again but this just resulted in the pavers crew filling the gap with finishing sand. Not the worst possible stop gap but now I need to finish repairs to the siding.
The pavers are laid approximately .75 in above the level of the foundation. I'm sure this is not ideal but the rest of the grading looks good and heavy rains have shown no signs of entering this area. That said, this is Texas so there will be flash flood situations every few years and we'll see how drainage works under those circumstances.
I had originally thought of emptying that gap filled with sand, installing replacement painted hardiplank and continuing the tradition of half assing the job and entombing it again.
Surely there is a professional way to handle this though. What would be suggested?

Don't you think you should have fixed the existing damage before proceeding with the overlay?

Gee, I never thought of that. I sure am glad I joined this forum!
